# What is wrong with this OAuth request to the Pocket API?

Tags: ruby, api, post, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth

I'm trying to build a simple script using the Pocket API and I'm getting a 400 bad request when following the documentation on the [site](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication). Here is what I get:

```
POST /v3/oauth/request?consumer_key=xxxxxx-
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback HTTP/1.1
Host: getpocket.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I am using Postman and I am running the redirect_uri from the rails server.

Additional information:

```
Cache-Control →private
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →15
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date →Mon, 21 Apr 2014 01:17:05 GMT
Expires →Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
P3P →policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE"
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Apache
Status →400 Bad Request
X-Error →Missing consumer key.
X-Error-Code →138
X-Source →Pocket
```

In a search to find out which x-error code was giving me a 400, I found that it's giving me a missing consumer key. I'm at a loss since this is a brand new key and I am certainly using it correctly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the consumer_key and redirect_uri as url parameters ?consumer_key=xxxxxx..

The correct way is to send them as form-data parameters:

[image: Postman Pocket API request]